# Using typeclasses wtih multiple type parameters

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass, simulacrum

I'm trying to use `symulacrum`'s `@typeclass` to avoid writing Ops/Syntax boilerplate. I have a trait parameterized with effect and a type:

```
@typeclass trait Close[F[_], T]{
    def close(t: T): F[Unit]
}
```

With the intention to be used as follows:

```
trait Stream[F[_], Pipe]{
    def open(): F[Pipe]
    def drain(): F[Unit]
}
object App{
    def runApp[F[_], Pipe: Close[F, ?]](implicit stream: Stream[F, Pipe]) = {
        for{
            pipe <- stream.open()
            _ <- stream.drain(pipe)
            _ <- pipe.close()
        } yield ()
    }
}
```

The reason I decided to put `Close[F[_], T]` away was that some `Pipe`s in my application are inherently unclosable so it is kind of wierd to put 
close method for all `Pipe`s

This is the error I get:

```
Error:(32, 4) @typeclass may only be applied to types that take a single type parameter
  @typeclass trait Close[F[_], T]
```

***QUESTION:*** In case of a `trait` has multiple type parameters (like `Close[F[_], T]`) do I have to write all the Ops/Syntax boilerplate on my own and symulacrum's `@typeclass` cannot help here?

Comment: I published small library https://github.com/DmytroMitin/AUXify Try annotation `@syntax` from there.
https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/7fe3e538434155f35a0fe30acb2af5c3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your own.

https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum#known-limitations

> **Known Limitations**
>
> - Only type classes that abstract over a proper type or a unary type constructor are currently supported.